# How to preserve control state within tab items in a TabControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, tabcontrol, state

I am a newcomer to WPF, attempting to build a project that follows the recommendations of Josh Smith's excellent article describing [The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Using Josh's sample code as a base, I have created a simple application that contains a number of "workspaces", each represented by a tab in a TabControl. In my application, a workspace is a document editor that allows a hierarchical document to be manipulated via a TreeView control.

Although I have succeeded in opening multiple workspaces and viewing their document content in the bound TreeView control, I find that the TreeView "forgets" its state when switching between tabs. For example, if the TreeView in Tab1 is partially expanded, it will be shown as fully collapsed after switching to Tab2 and returning to Tab1. This behaviour appears to apply to all aspects of control state for all controls.

After some experimentation, I have realized that I can preserve state within a TabItem by explicitly binding each control state property to a dedicated property on the underlying ViewModel. However, this seems like a lot of additional work, when I simply want all my controls to remember their state when switching between workspaces.

I assume I am missing something simple, but I am not sure where to look for the answer. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tim

Update:

As requested, I will attempt to post some code that demonstrates this problem. However, since the data that underlies the TreeView is complex, I will post a simplified example that exhibits the same symtoms. Here is the XAML from the main window:

```
<TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Docs}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <view:DocumentView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The above XAML correctly binds to an ObservableCollection of DocumentViewModel, whereby each member is presented via a DocumentView.

For the simplicity of this example, I have removed the TreeView (mentioned above) from the DocumentView and replaced it with a TabControl containing 3 fixed tabs:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="A" />
    <TabItem Header="B" />
    <TabItem Header="C" />
</TabControl>
```

In this scenario, there is no binding between the DocumentView and the DocumentViewModel. When the code is run, the inner TabControl is unable to remember its selection when the outer TabControl is switched.

However, if I explicitly bind the inner TabControl's SelectedIndex property ...

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedDocumentIndex}">
    <TabItem Header="A" />
    <TabItem Header="B" />
    <TabItem Header="C" />
</TabControl>
```

... to a corresponding dummy property on the DocumentViewModel ...

```
public int SelecteDocumentIndex { get; set; }
```

... the inner tab is able to remember its selection.

I understand that I can effectively solve my problem by applying this technique to every visual property of every control, but I am hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Controls in WPF 'remember' their state by default, the fact that the controls in your tab items 'forget' their state, is the result of some explicit action on your part. Show the XAML for your tab items, and the relevant view model code for the bindings they contain.

Comment: I agree with Aviad, hard to tell what's going wrong without seeing your code.  For some great articles on the TreeView control in WPF, I suggest taking a look at Bea Stollnitz's blog ... http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/index.php?s=treeview

Comment: I take my comment back, this is a real nasty issue, I just tried it from all angles, and if the tab control is using an `ItemsSource` with a `DataTemplate` it appears that the visual state of the controls in the data template is **shared (!!!)** among the tab items!

Comment: I've had this problem with more than just a treeview... if you don't have a two-way ViewModel backing the state of the control, it will lose it.  The reason for this is that when you switch tabs, the controls are no longer part of the visual tree.  The Unload event is actually fired for these controls and they no longer have any visual representation until you switch back.  This is a form of virtualization that the tab control implements to help save memory when you have a lot of tabs.  Very interested to know if you come up with a solution for this... I've just been creating the VMs.

Comment: @Anderson Imes: Really, that comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Scott Whitlock - yes, I agree, Anderson Imes' comment seems to be as close as I am likely to get to a solution to this problem. +1.

Comment: @Scott Whitlock thanks... I sort of feel like there might still be some sort of workaround, though.  Maybe some WPF maven will come along and give us a real way to preserve visual state.

Comment: Is there a way to watch the Visual Tree to see if there is a change? I am trying to apply ValidationRules to all Bindings on FrameworkElements within my Visual Tree. Since the tree changes, I am having problems applying bindings to the elements.

Comment: Can you show us how you solved this please? The answer below I feel does not answer the question...

Comment: @Killercam: IIRC, the WAF sample that existed in January 2010 was very helpful in guiding me to a workable solution, but has subsequently evolved considerably, to the extent that it tries to do many things, and is no longer very clear on this point. I recently re-visited it to refresh my memory (not having worked with WPF for almost 3 years) and was disappointed to discover that I couldn't reproduce what I had achieved previously. In the end, I resorted to simply creating additional visual state properties on the view model. Sorry that I can't suggest something more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Writer sample application of the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com) shows how to solve your issue. It creates a new UserControl for every TabItem. So the state is preserved when the user changes the active Tab.

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer at all. It point you to a large application - how do you fix the problem outlined above explicitly??

Comment: The mention of creating a new `UserControl` for every `TabItem` is what helped me. I basically just wrapped my data object in a `UserControl` by setting the data object to the `UserControl.Content` property and that solved my performance issue.

Comment: How does one "set the data object to the UserControl.Content"?

Comment: I also don't find this answer very helpful. It took me a pretty long time trying to find out how it was really done in the Writer sample application. What I noticed is this: They keep a reference to the View in their ViewModel. I guess this prevents the View and its state from getting lost. However I haven't checked if this really solves my specific problem (which is exactly the same as the OP). I would prefer a solution where the ViewModel does not need to know the View (but instead using DataTemplates, as in the OP).

Comment: @LineloDude I think he means it the other way round? So setting the UserControl.Content to the data object. (ie `myUserControl.Content = myDataObject`)

Answer (score 6):

I got resolve it with this tip `WPF TabControl: Turning Off Tab Virtualization` at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460989/WPF-TabControl-Turning-Off-Tab-Virtualization this a class of TabContent with property IsCached.

Comment: solution seems to work: one file to include, least amount of intrusive code. havent run into any of the con's described in code project.

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem and found a [nice solution](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/Controls/NonReloadingTabControl.cs) you can use it like a normal `TabControl` as far as i tested it. In case it it important for you here the [Current License](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/LICENSE)

### Here the Code on case the Link goes down:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace CefSharp.Wpf.Example.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extended TabControl which saves the displayed item so you don't get the performance hit of
    /// unloading and reloading the VisualTree when switching tabs
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Based on example from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9802346, which in turn is based on
    /// http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/eburke/archive/2009/04/30/keeping-the-wpf-tab-control-from-destroying-its-children.aspx
    /// with some modifications so it reuses a TabItem's ContentPresenter when doing drag/drop operations
    /// </remarks>
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ItemsHolder", Type = typeof(Panel))]
    public class NonReloadingTabControl : TabControl
    {
        private Panel itemsHolderPanel;

        public NonReloadingTabControl()
        {
            // This is necessary so that we get the initial databound selected item
            ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGeneratorStatusChanged;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If containers are done, generate the selected item
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void ItemContainerGeneratorStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
            {
                ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= ItemContainerGeneratorStatusChanged;
                UpdateSelectedItem();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the ItemsHolder and generate any children
        /// </summary>
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            itemsHolderPanel = GetTemplateChild("PART_ItemsHolder") as Panel;
            UpdateSelectedItem();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// When the items change we remove any generated panel children and add any new ones as necessary
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnItemsChanged(e);

            if (itemsHolderPanel == null)
                return;

            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                itemsHolderPanel.Children.Clear();
                break;

                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                if (e.OldItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                    {
                        var cp = FindChildContentPresenter(item);
                        if (cp != null)
                            itemsHolderPanel.Children.Remove(cp);
                    }
                }

                // Don't do anything with new items because we don't want to
                // create visuals that aren't being shown

                UpdateSelectedItem();
                break;

                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Replace not implemented yet");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
            UpdateSelectedItem();
        }

        private void UpdateSelectedItem()
        {
            if (itemsHolderPanel == null)
                return;

            // Generate a ContentPresenter if necessary
            var item = GetSelectedTabItem();
            if (item != null)
                CreateChildContentPresenter(item);

            // show the right child
            foreach (ContentPresenter child in itemsHolderPanel.Children)
                child.Visibility = ((child.Tag as TabItem).IsSelected) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private ContentPresenter CreateChildContentPresenter(object item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                return null;

            var cp = FindChildContentPresenter(item);

            if (cp != null)
                return cp;

            var tabItem = item as TabItem;
            cp = new ContentPresenter
            {
                Content = (tabItem != null) ? tabItem.Content : item,
                ContentTemplate = this.SelectedContentTemplate,
                ContentTemplateSelector = this.SelectedContentTemplateSelector,
                ContentStringFormat = this.SelectedContentStringFormat,
                Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed,
                Tag = tabItem ?? (this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item))
            };
            itemsHolderPanel.Children.Add(cp);
            return cp;
        }

        private ContentPresenter FindChildContentPresenter(object data)
        {
            if (data is TabItem)
                data = (data as TabItem).Content;

            if (data == null)
                return null;

            if (itemsHolderPanel == null)
                return null;

            foreach (ContentPresenter cp in itemsHolderPanel.Children)
            {
                if (cp.Content == data)
                    return cp;
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected TabItem GetSelectedTabItem()
        {
            var selectedItem = SelectedItem;
            if (selectedItem == null)
                return null;

            var item = selectedItem as TabItem ?? ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(SelectedIndex) as TabItem;

            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

### License at Copietime

```
// Copyright © 2010-2016 The CefSharp Authors
//
// Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
// modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
// met:
//
//    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
//      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
//
//    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
//      copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer
//      in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
//      distribution.
//
//    * Neither the name of Google Inc. nor the name Chromium Embedded
//      Framework nor the name CefSharp nor the names of its contributors
//      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
//      without specific prior written permission.
//
// THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
// "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
// LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
// A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
// OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
// SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
// LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
// DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
// THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
// (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
// OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Arsen's answer above, here is another behavior, that:

1. Doesn't need any additional references. (unless you put the code in an external library)
2. It doesn't use a base class.
3. It handles both Reset and Add collection changes.

**To use it**

Declare the namespace in the xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    ...
    xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:My.Behaviors;assembly=My.Wpf.Assembly"
    ...
    >
```

Update the style:

```
<Style TargetType="TabControl" x:Key="TabControl">
    ...
    <Setter Property="behaviors:TabControlBehavior.DoNotCacheControls" Value="True" />
    ...
</Style>
```

**Or** update the TabControl directly:

```
<TabControl behaviors:TabControlBehavior.DoNotCacheControls="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
```

And here is the code for the behavior:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace My.Behaviors
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps tab item contents in UserControl to prevent TabControl from re-using its content
    /// </summary>
    public class TabControlBehavior
    {
        private static readonly HashSet<TabControl> _tabControls = new HashSet<TabControl>();
        private static readonly Dictionary<ItemCollection, TabControl> _tabControlItemCollections = new Dictionary<ItemCollection, TabControl>();

        public static bool GetDoNotCacheControls(TabControl tabControl)
        {
            return (bool)tabControl.GetValue(DoNotCacheControlsProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDoNotCacheControls(TabControl tabControl, bool value)
        {
            tabControl.SetValue(DoNotCacheControlsProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DoNotCacheControlsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DoNotCacheControls",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(TabControlBehavior),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnDoNotCacheControlsChanged));

        private static void OnDoNotCacheControlsChanged(
            DependencyObject depObj,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var tabControl = depObj as TabControl;
            if (null == tabControl)
                return;
            if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
                return;

            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                Attach(tabControl);
            else
                Detach(tabControl);
        }

        private static void Attach(TabControl tabControl)
        {
            if (!_tabControls.Add(tabControl))
                return;
            _tabControlItemCollections.Add(tabControl.Items, tabControl);
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)tabControl.Items).CollectionChanged += TabControlUcWrapperBehavior_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private static void Detach(TabControl tabControl)
        {
            if (!_tabControls.Remove(tabControl))
                return;
            _tabControlItemCollections.Remove(tabControl.Items);
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)tabControl.Items).CollectionChanged -= TabControlUcWrapperBehavior_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private static void TabControlUcWrapperBehavior_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var itemCollection = (ItemCollection)sender;
            var tabControl = _tabControlItemCollections[itemCollection];
            IList items;
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {   /* our ObservableArray<T> swops out the whole collection */
                items = (ItemCollection)sender;
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.Action != NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                    return;

                items = e.NewItems;
            }

            foreach (var newItem in items)
            {
                var ti = tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(newItem) as TabItem;
                if (ti != null)
                {
                    var userControl = ti.Content as UserControl;
                    if (null == userControl)
                        ti.Content = new UserControl { Content = ti.Content };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, how do you modify it to use a ContentTemplate?

Answer (score 1):

Using the idea of WAF I come to this simple solution which seems to solve the issue.

I use Interactivity Behavior, but the same can be done with attached property if  Interactivity library is not referenced

```
/// <summary>
/// Wraps tab item contents in UserControl to prevent TabControl from re-using its content
/// </summary>
public class TabControlUcWrapperBehavior 
    : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    private TabControl AssociatedTabControl { get { return (TabControl) AssociatedObject; } }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)AssociatedTabControl.Items).CollectionChanged += TabControlUcWrapperBehavior_CollectionChanged;
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)AssociatedTabControl.Items).CollectionChanged -= TabControlUcWrapperBehavior_CollectionChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    void TabControlUcWrapperBehavior_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action != NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add) 
            return;

        foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
        {
            var ti = AssociatedTabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(newItem) as TabItem;

            if (ti != null && !(ti.Content is UserControl)) 
                ti.Content = new UserControl { Content = ti.Content };
        }
    }
}
```

And usage

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="...">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <controls:TabControlUcWrapperBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: I am trying out your solution, but what I'm seeing is that ti.Content is the view model, and not the control from the template.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check if you are calling ItemFromContainer method instead of ContainerFromItem ?

Comment: ah, do you have DataTemplate for that viewmodel?

Comment: The TabControl has a DataTemplate defined in the TabControl.ContentTemplate property.  That DataTemplate has a grid which displays the data in the view model.

Comment: can you send me sample that not working to mkrtchyan.arsen at gmail com I will check

Answer (score -1):

I have posted an answer for similar question. In my case manually creating the TabItems have solved the problem of creating the View again and again. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21005627/912857)