# How Do I refresh window in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a small project I am working on which is a window with 4 WPF tabs on it.

The first tab is where I do most of the work, but occasionally I need to move back to other tabs. One of these tabs has a DataGrid that is bound to a list that is affected by the main tab I stay on.

When I update something on the first tab, I need it to cause a refresh on the data in the Datagrid(usually just to update a value).

The only way it has been working is if I click on the header myself.

How can I do this in code?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is the list an `ObservableCollection` or properties implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Have you tried:

```
myDatagrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

```
this.NavigationService.Refresh();
```

or

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("<EnterPage name here.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Note for new visitors : This will not apply for regular Window controls. Mainly deals with Page, Frame, NavigationWindow. Read more in MSDN about how it works. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I used this workaround, it's no perfect but works

```
MainWindow newWindow = new MainWindow();
Application.Current.MainWindow = newWindow;
newWindow.Show();
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

this might be of interest to you: [How to preserve control state within tab items in a TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080764/wpf-tabcontrol-how-to-preserve-control-state-within-tab-items-mvvm-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on an Object that you are displaying shared properties you could implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and refresh the DataGrid. If its a collection you could look at the [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) class.