# TabControl DataTemplate Instance Creation Issues

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, tabcontrol

I have a WPF issue that I don't understand - can anyone help?

The WPF below is used as the ContentTemplate for a standard TabControl and resides within a ResourceDictionary. MyElementItemsControl is a simple derivative of ItemsControl and MyDesignCanvas is a simple derivative of Canvas.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabContent"  x:Shared="False">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="contentScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                <Grid>
                    <View:MyElementItemsControl BorderBrush="Transparent" x:Name="schedulePanel" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}" Background="White">
                        <View:MyElementItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <View:MyDesignCanvas Height="1000" Width="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                                                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                                     Background="Transparent">
                                </View:MyDesignCanvas>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </View:MyElementItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </View:MyElementItemsControl>

                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                                    <Binding ElementName="SlideZoom" Path="Value" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                </ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                                <ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
                                    <Binding ElementName="SlideZoom" Path="Value" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                </ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
                            </ScaleTransform>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>

                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>

        </Grid>

        <Slider Opacity="0.5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" Grid.Row="1" Name="SlideZoom" Orientation="Horizontal" Minimum="0.1" Maximum="3" Value="1">
        </Slider>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I run the code I get two issues I don't understand:

1. I seem to only get a single ScrollViewer when I would expect a ScrollViewer per item. So if I add two tab items and make the canvas different sizes, the scroll bars are adjusted to the size of the biggest canvas only. I expected that the Shared=False attribute would create new instances of the template for each tab.
2. Maybe related to item 1 - if I stick a breakpoint on the constructor of MyDesignCanvas it gets hit when the first tab is added but not when other tabs are added. Only when I start closing tabs does the breakpoint get hit again - I would expect a hit on each tab addition.

I guess I don't really understand data templating enough, so can anyone explain what might be going on or point me at some resources that may help me diagnose this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've realised what the issue is - the WPF TabControl does internal virtualization of tab content, so has been re-using the tab contents and just changing the data context despite me using Shared=False. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993159/why-do-tab-controls-reuse-view-instances-when-changing-tab) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080764/how-to-preserve-control-state-within-tab-items-in-a-tabcontrol) for more details.