# How to stop Wpf Tabcontrol to unload Visual tree on Tab change

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

Hi My usercontrols placed in tabs are unloaded and loaded every time the tabs are changed.It creates some unnecessary lag in the application.I am looking for some way to fix this behavior.I know i have to subclass tabcontrol to change this behavior but how..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find two different approaches to prevent this in this StackOverflow question:

- [WPF TabControl - how to preserve control state within tab items (MVVM pattern)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080764/wpf-tabcontrol-how-to-preserve-control-state-within-tab-items-mvvm-pattern)

I recommend:

- [Keeping the WPF Tab Control from destroying its children](http://web.archive.org/web/20120429044747/http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2009/04/26/22.09.28)

Comment: The recommended option sample project is dead - anyone have a mirror for it?