# Why does a tabchange change a bound value

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, tabcontrol

I have a problem with a UserControl I wrote, when I use it in a TabControl of our application.
The TabControl is DataBound and uses Templates. On change of the current Tab (per MouseClick) a bound property is set to null. I would like to keep the currently selected item in the ViewModel. If I use a DataGrid or ListBox everything works as espected. The SelectedItem-Property of the ViewModel is not set to null.

Maybe I have to setup my DependencyProperty different? The involved properties are defined like this:

```
SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(BusinessListEditor), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(BusinessListEditor), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
```

This properties are directly bound to a DataGrid inside the UserControl.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgDataGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource,
                                    ElementName=ucBusinessListEditor}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,
                                     ElementName=ucBusinessListEditor}"
              Style="{Binding DataGridStyle,
                              ElementName=ucBusinessListEditor}" />
```

The question how I can prevent the SelectedItem-Property from changing on a SelectedTab-Change. I tried to analyse this but do not fully understand the case. Somehow the SelectedItemChanged comes from a ItemsChanged of the DataGrid.

Comment: Did you try to set the binding for `SelectedItem` as `Mode=OneWayToSource`?

Comment: Tried it now, doesn't help. And I would not have the possibility to set the SelectedItem from the ViewModel...

Comment: Sorry, just wrong enumeration value! You should use Mode=OneWay

Comment: But then it will not update when the selected item in the DataGrid changed, or?

Comment: No. I thought you didn't want it.

Comment: I need both. I just don't want that when i change the current tab that the value of selecteditem of the BusinessListEditor will change to null.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the current tab the old one will be unloaded from visual tree. This means no `DataGrid`, no `SelectedItem`.

You could try to [stop this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5038107/620360) or maybe simpler backup the last SelectedItem from your DP that isn't null in a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx).

Comment: So why the SelectedItem of the ViewModel is not set to null if I use a DataGrid or ListBox, but it is set to null if I use the BusinessListEditor?

Comment: I can't say. I don't know your BusinessListEditor and the structure of your application.

Comment: For this properties shown above no additional logic exists. Just this two properties plus the DataGrid inside.