# DataGrid loses selection, sorting, grouping, ... on changing the tab in my WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I build an app on hand of the MVVM pattern [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

I use the [DataGrid](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid&referringTitle=Home) of the [extended WPF toolkit.](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Everytime when I change the tab and return to the datagrid all settings like sorting, selection and grouping are lost.

I read that I can keep these settings in an additional property but why I have to do this?

What is the trigger for the datagrid that it refreshs its view? How can I prevent the datagrid to do that?

Comment: How do you navigate from one tab to the other? what code is executed on tab changes? how does the datagrid definition look like?

Comment: the code is nearly the same like in the linked mvvm pattern. I add some modifications in my code

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the tab control, it load and unload every time you switch the tabitems. there are some posts around how you can change this behavior.

an another way would be to persist the datagrid states and apply it on load.

Comment: thanks for the hint. what is better? workaround for the tabcontrol or the datagrid? Where can I find the workaround for the tabcontrol?

Comment: just google :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038107/how-to-stop-wpf-tabcontrol-to-unload-visual-tree-on-tab-change