# How to set Ellipse style trigger on TabControl to highlight when DataGrids has selection

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, datatrigger, ellipse

I have an `Ellipse` in each `TabControl` header which is to highlight blue if there is any items selected in the `DataGrid` below it, otherwise it should be Transparent. At the moment I have the `Trigger` in reverse so if the `DataGrid` `SelectedItems.Count` is 0 it is Transparent, if there is someway to have the default as transparent that would be nice.

Note: It will have multiple tabs and associated `DataGrids`.

How can I get the `Style` `Trigger` working correctly on the `Ellipse`?

[image]

```
<TabControl Name="tcGeometry" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding GEOMETRIES}" >
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>                            
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DISPLAY_NAME}" Margin="0,0,25,0"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="SelectionIndicator"
                         Width="8" Height="8"
                         Stroke="Black"
                         Fill="Blue"
                         StrokeThickness="1"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Ellipse.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  SelectedItems.Count, ElementName=dgAudit}"  Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Ellipse.Style>
                </Ellipse>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
                <DataGrid Name="dgAudit" 
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          IsReadOnly="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding GEOM_ASSET_OC_LIST}"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
                          RowHeaderWidth="30" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: You can bind the `Tag` property of each `TabItem` to the corresponding `DataGrid` and use this in your `Trigger`'s binding property path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the a local value for the `Fill` property of the `Ellipse`. Set the default value in a `Style` setter.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="SelectionIndicator"
                         Width="8" Height="8"
                         Stroke="Black"
                         StrokeThickness="1"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Ellipse.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, ElementName=dgAudit}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Ellipse.Style>
</Ellipse>
```

Local values take precedence over values set in styles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence

You may also have to bind to the `Count` property of a *source collection* that keeps track of the selected items rather than binding to the `SelectedItems` property of the `DataGrid` element. This is because a `TabControl` by default unloads the visual tree of the unselect tab when you switch tabs:

[How to stop Wpf Tabcontrol to unload Visual tree on Tab change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038107/how-to-stop-wpf-tabcontrol-to-unload-visual-tree-on-tab-change)

Comment: unfortunately the trigger still doesn't respond to when SelectedItems.Count = 0. The ellipse's fill is always blue, any ideas on what could be going on? I select and deselect an item and there is no change.

Comment: Creating a seperate collection of the SelectedItems worked, also I found that binding IsSelected on the DataGridRow to the row data object stops the actual selection from disappearing.