# When changing back from another TabItem, all Data Validation (IDataError) infos were disappeading

Tags: c#, wpf, idataerrorinfo

A VS2017 solution illustrating this issue: https://github.com/ShannonZ/playground.git

**IDataErrorInfo**
I implemented IDataErrorInfo in my ViewModel class.
ViewModel only has two props X & Y and X+Y should not be larger than 10.

**ValidatesOnDataErrors=True**
All TextBox binding to X/Y were set ValidatesOnDataErrors=True

**What's QUIRK**
The two TextBox-es were red highlighted because X+Y=13>10 at beginning.
Then if you change to the second TabItem and  go back to the first one again, the two TextBox-es shows in a normal state. Even if you change the value manually (keep X+Y>10), the Error infos would not show again.
[image]
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days tracking and inspecting, I found that the Validation.Error informations are shown in the Adorner Layer, when you switch tabs, that layer is discarded.
The way to solve it is simple: Add content inside an AdornerDecorator.

```
<TabItem>
<AdornerDecorator>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the fact that tabitem contents are unloaded when you change tab. 
Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038107/how-to-stop-wpf-tabcontrol-to-unload-visual-tree-on-tab-change)

Comment: Not caused by TabItem unload or Virtualization because if there were no errors before changing to another item, after changing back, the Data Validation performed well.