# WPF slow when TabControl bound to ViewModels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have `TabControl` bound directly to `IEnumerable<ViewModelBase>` (different ViewModels), rendered using `DataTemplates`. **BUT** when switching Tabs, one can se that `TabItems` are completely redrawed and it's soooo slow. Is it normal???

Comment: How complicated are the `DataTemplates`? Do you have everything in the `DataTemplate` or does the `DataTemplate` only contain a `UserControl` and is used to match that up to the ViewModel?

Comment: Problem solved! It was the lazy-loading of some attributes.

Comment: So what was the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your data context truly exposing an `IEnumerable<T>` as the binding source? If so, I recommend you take a look at [How Data Binding References are Resolved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx#HowDataBindingReferencesAreResolved). This won't explicitly address the redraw issue, but if you expose your view models data source using a collection that supports the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface such as [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) or a [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) data source, you will get better binding and rendering performance.

On the redraw side of this issue, you should take a look at [this Dr. WPF post](http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/browse_thread/thread/6f3531a1720252dd). There is a proposed solution to the performance issue you are seeing, and to go one step further you would write a TabControl subsclass, and possibly use a [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx) as the items source of the custom TabControl.

This [article](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=338) goes over the UI and data virtualization options you might try.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, DataTemplates are blueprints of how to construct objects, so your TabControl might very well throw the old tab content and and create a new one if you switch tabs. Possibly [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080764/wpf-tabcontrol-how-to-preserve-control-state-within-tab-items-mvvm-pattern) is related.

(*Even though people have complained before about the behaviour that the TabControl may actually reuse objects, i suppose this could depend on the underlying type of the items*)